# Cross-platform paths handling specifying format

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Latest .NET (Core) versions, that run on Windows and Linux, support paths handling on both formats, depending on where the application is running.

The problem is, although it supports dealing with Windows paths if running on Windows and dealing with Linux paths if running on Linux, I see no way of specifying the format of the path I want to manipulate.

For instance, the following code:

```cs
string windowsPath = @"abc\xyz";
string linuxPath = @"abc/xyz";

Console.WriteLine("Windows file name: " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(windowsPath));
Console.WriteLine("Linux file name: " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(linuxPath));
```

produces the following result if running on Windows:

```
Windows file name: xyz
Linux file name: xyz
```

and the following result if running on Linux:

```
Windows file name: abc\xyz
Linux file name: xyz
```

Is it possible to, on an application running on Linux, tell System.IO.Path methods that I want to handle paths on Windows format? Something I would imagine it would be `Path.GetFileName(windowsPath, OSPlatform.Windows)` or similar.
Or is there any NuGet package that allows this?

### TLDR:

If I am running a .NET application on Linux and I want to handle paths with System.IO.Path that I know are in Windows format, is there a way to specify it? Or is there a NuGet package that allows this?

Answer (score 0):

If you got the Windows path string from somewhere and your application did not compose it by itself, replace the `\` characters with `/` characters before using the path string. There should be no need for some fancy-schmanzy library to do just that. However, this is only sufficient for "simple" relative paths.

However, Windows paths can be in the form of UNC paths or start with a drive letter. If it is possible that your application might be confronted with such paths, you need to determine a strategy for your application scenario of how to deal with them.

On the other hand, if your application itself composes those path strings, preferably use the `System.IO.Path.Combine` method, or make use of the host OS-dependent directory path separator provided by `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`.

Comment: My point is: if System.IO.Path.Combine and other System.IO.Path methods already have the ability to deal with multiple platform path formats (as they will behave differently depending on which platform the application is running), is there really the need for us to manually handle strings, replace slash characters and such? Also, as you mentioned, this works only for simple paths.